# Building a connection log system

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary, logging

I'm building a "Smart" Log System, where I'm capable of monitoring customers connections, like, start and stop connection establishment time to server.

**RAW LOG**:

```
Dec 19 00:00:03 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info <pppoe-customer1>: terminating... - peer is not responding
Dec 19 00:00:03 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info,account customer1 logged out, 4486 1009521 23444247 12573 18159
Dec 19 00:00:03 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info <pppoe-customer1>: disconnected
Dec 19 00:00:07 172.16.20.24 pppoe,info PPPoE connection established from 60:E3:27:A2:60:09
Dec 19 00:00:08 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info,account customer2 logged in, 10.171.3.185
Dec 19 00:00:08 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info <pppoe-customer2>: authenticated
Dec 19 00:00:08 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info <pppoe-customer2>: connected
Dec 19 00:00:13 172.16.20.24 pppoe,info PPPoE connection established from C0:25:E9:7F:C0:41
Dec 19 00:00:14 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,error <ccfa>: user customer3 authentication failed
Dec 19 00:00:32 172.16.20.24 pppoe,info PPPoE connection established from C0:25:E9:7F:C0:41
Dec 19 00:00:36 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,error <ccfb>: user customer3 authentication failed
Dec 19 00:01:06 172.16.20.24 pppoe,info PPPoE connection established from C0:25:E9:7F:C0:41
```

What are important for me: capture lines with *connected* and *disconnected* strings.

I got this:

```
import os
import re
import sys

f = open('log.log','r')
log = []
for line in f:
 if re.search(r': connected|: disconnected',line):
  ob = dict()
  ob['USER'] = re.search(r'<pppoe(.*?)>',line).group(0).replace("<pppoe-","").replace(">","")
  ob['DATA'] = re.search(r'^\w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}',line).group(0)
  ob['CONNECTION'] = re.search(r': .*',line).group(0).replace(": ", "")
  log.append(ob)
```

I'm still learning, so that's not the most brilliant regex, but it's ok! 
Need **now refine this log list**, want to get to this sample:

```
{"connection" : [{
"start" : "Dec 19 10:12:58", 
"username" : "customer2"}

{"connection" : [{
"start" : "Dec 20 10:12:58", 
"username" : "customer1"}

{"connection" : [{
"start" : "Dec 19 10:12:58", 
"stop" : Dec 22 10:04:35",
"username" : "customer4"}

{"connection" : [{
"start" : "Dec 19 10:12:58",
"stop" : "Dec 24 10:04:35" 
"username" : "customer3"}
```

My obstacles,

- The RAW Log is constantly being generated, I need to identify if some
  user already exists.
  IF YES: update connection (customer2 drops his connections, need registre it!) but What's happen if he has constants drop connections?

For example:

```
Dec 19 10:20:58 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info <pppoe-customer2>: disconnected    
Dec 19 01:00:36 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,error <ccfb>: user customer3 authentication failed
Dec 19 01:01:06 172.16.20.24 pppoe,info PPPoE connection established from C0:25:E9:7F:C0:41
Dec 19 10:21:38 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info <pppoe-customer2>: authenticated
Dec 19 10:21:48 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info <pppoe-customer2>: connected
Dec 19 10:22:38 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info <pppoe-customer3>: authenticated
Dec 19 10:22:58 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info <pppoe-customer2>: disconnected
```

First disconnection, simple to add it.

```
{"connection" : [{
"start" : "Dec 19 10:12:58"
"stop" : "Dec 19 10:20:58", 
"username" : "customer2"}
```

In the next authentication, I need to search this specific user, insert new "start" connection time and erase "stop". And so on.

```
{"connection" : [{
"start" : "Dec 19 10:21:48" 
"username" : "customer2"}
```

- Next challenger to me, its create this new refine list.

Tried to make this, but does not work!

```
conn = []
for l in log:
 obcon = dict()
 if not obcon:
    obcon['USER'] = l['USER']
    if l['DATA'] == 'connected':
        obcon['START'] = l['DATA']      
        obcon['STOP'] = ""
    else:
        obcon['STOP'] = l['DATA']
 conn.append(obcon)
```

Before build the new list, I'd need to check if exists some user, if not, let's build it! The ['CONNECTION'] I use to identify starts/stop connections:

```
Disconnected -> STOP
Connected -> START
```

I dont know if I need to be more specific. 
Need ideas. Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the var `log` should be of type `dict` as it will help you find an existing user data more easily.
Next, you used `re(...).group(0)` everywhere, which is the [entire matching string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group). For example, when extracting the user name, you wrote `'<pppoe(.*?)>'`, but it is located in `group(1)` (in regex, parentheses are used for match extraction).
My suggestion is (Note - I removed the imports of `sys` and `os` as they are not in use):

```
import re

f = open('log.log', 'r')
log = dict()
for line in f:
    reg = re.search(r': ((?:dis)?connected)', line) # finds connected or disconnected
    if reg is not None:
        user = re.search(r'<pppoe-(.*?)>', line).group(1)
        # if the user in the log, get it, else create it with empty dict
        ob = log.setdefault(user, dict({'USER': user})) 
        ob['CONNECTION'] = reg.group(1)
        time = re.search(r'^\w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', line).group(0)
        if ob['CONNECTION'].startswith('dis'):
            ob['END'] = time
        else:
            ob['START'] = time
            if 'END' in ob:
                ob.pop('END')
```

If the log file is:

```
Dec 19 00:00:03 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info <pppoe-customer1>: terminating... - peer is not responding
Dec 19 00:00:03 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info,account customer1 logged out, 4486 1009521 23444247 12573 18159
Dec 19 00:00:03 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info <pppoe-customer1>: disconnected
Dec 19 00:00:07 172.16.20.24 pppoe,info PPPoE connection established from 00:00:00:00:00:00
Dec 19 00:00:08 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info,account customer2 logged in, 127.0.0.1
Dec 19 00:00:08 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info <pppoe-customer2>: authenticated
Dec 19 00:00:08 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info <pppoe-customer2>: connected
Dec 19 00:00:13 172.16.20.24 pppoe,info PPPoE connection established from 00:00:00:00:00:00
Dec 19 00:00:14 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,error <ccfa>: user customer3 authentication failed
Dec 19 00:02:03 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info,account customer2 logged out, 4486 1009521 23444247 12573 18159
Dec 19 00:02:03 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info <pppoe-customer2>: disconnected
Dec 19 00:02:08 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info,account customer3 logged in, 127.0.0.1
Dec 19 00:02:08 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info <pppoe-customer3>: authenticated
Dec 19 00:02:08 172.16.20.24 pppoe,ppp,info <pppoe-customer3>: connected
```

the value of `log` will be:

```
{
    'customer1': {
        'CONNECTION': 'disconnected',
        'END': 'Dec 19 00:00:03',
        'USER': 'customer1'
    }, 
    'customer3': {
        'START': 'Dec 19 00:02:08',
        'CONNECTION': 'connected',
        'USER': 'customer3'
    }, 
    'customer2': {
        'START': 'Dec 19 00:00:08',
        'CONNECTION': 'disconnected',
        'END': 'Dec 19 00:02:03', 
        'USER': 'customer2'
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great! But I have another question. I have 11 LOGs similar to that, what you think? Will I need to put it in a function and "instantiate" it to each LOG? I mean, Every time a row is added to the log, it will do the FOR again? Did you understand or I'm being confused?

Comment: @TMoraes hmm, I'm unable to understand your need exactly. Try to explain it again please

Comment: never mind, I will try another way! Thanks again bro :)